# Removing numbers from a character list using java

Tags: java

I wanted to display the numbers occuring in a character list and then remove that number. Here is my code:

package mytrials;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyTrials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    list.add('a');
    list.add('1');
    list.add('5');
    System.out.println(list.size());
    for( ListIterator i = list.listIterator(list.size());  i.hasPrevious();){
        Character c = (Character) i.previous();
        if( Character.isDigit(c)){
            System.out.println(c + " is a digit");
            list.remove(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list.size());
}
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
3
5 is a digit
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
at java.util.AbstractList$ListItr.previous(AbstractList.java:386)
at mytrials.MyTrials.main(MyTrials.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

What is the cause of this error and how can it be rectified.

Comment: you are using ListIterator , which is not a fail-safe iterator , that is why you are getting a concurrentmodificationexception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
i.remove();
```

instead of

```
list.remove(c);
```

[See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

Use Iterator instead of the for-each(loop) construct when you need to:

- Remove the current element.
  The for-each construct hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove. Therefore, the for-each construct is not usable for filtering.
- Iterate over multiple collections in parallel.

Comment: This is indeed the problem, +1. I wonder how many questions with this answer that exist on SO. :)

Comment: An explanation would be a nice complement.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove with your iterator :

```
i.remove(); // instead of list.remove(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that the iterator's list was modified by using `list.remove(c);`.When a list is modified directly, the iterator becomes invalid, thus causing your error.

As Achintya Jha posted, you should use the iterator's remove function

Answer (score 0):

list-iterator is a fail-fast iterator and throws an exception when a thread is trying to modify the list content while another thread is iterating it.

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549927/fail-fast-iterator) 
[and this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)