# Null pointer with iterator.next

Tags: java, collections

Here below is a code snippet in java.

```
Collection contextPages = (Collection) getContextPages();
Iterator contextPageIter = contextPages.iterator();
while (contextPageIter.hasNext()) {
    Page contextPage = (Page) contextPageIter.next();
    String result = contextPage.getResult();        // <-- Null pointer exception here
    // Other stuff which this API does.
}
```

This code has been in production for a while. But for some reason, we hit a null pointer at `String result = contextPage.getResult();`.

So looks like even though we did a check for `hasNext()`, the `next()` method is returning `null`.

One possibility is that the collection itself has a `null`, but is it possible that this code could yield to a null pointer in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Normally, it is not allowed to modify a collection concurrently.  However, there is no guarantee that this will be detected by the collection (though [it will try to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549956/1392132)).  It would help to know the exact class of `contextPages`.

Comment: _Anything_ could happen if the collection is not thread-safe, and one thread modifies the collection while another thread is using an Iterator for the collection.  Do you have some reason to suspect that another thread may be using the collection at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Some collections allow you to add a null, so iter.next will return it and when you use it -> NPE

To demonstrate

```
@Test
public void testNull() {
    Collection<Object> c = new ArrayList<>();
    c.add(null);
    Iterator<Object> iterator = c.iterator();
    Assert.assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
    Object o = iterator.next();
    Assert.assertNull(o);
}
```

So check that you don't add `null` references to the collection or check for `null` before using the result of `Iterator#next()`

```
Page contextPage = (Page) contextPageIter.next();
String result = null;
if(contextPage != null) {
        result = contextPage.getResult();
}
```

There should be no difference between single- and multi- threaded applications, just make sure you don't add `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to check for null before using the result of Iterator.next()

Try this -

```
Page contextPage = (Page) contextPageIter.next();
String result = null;
if(contextPage != null) {
        result = contextPage.getResult();
}
```